# Not being able to parse request object in a post request

Tags: node.js, express

I went through so much Q&As here with no solution. I know few things about HTTP requests and Express so let's try to put some related code. (as this was working to some point, I cannot track where it went wrong). All I know is I've been playing with middle-wares at application level and at route level.

**Client code**

`<form action="/listings/donations" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`

The requested route is being called fine.

**App level middle-wares**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
```

I also add some home made middle-wares

```
req.body = _.object(_.map(req.body, function (value, key) {
  if (value && value.length) {
    return [key, value.trim()]
  } else {
    return [key, value]
  }
}))
```

This is to trim all values (as I expect so much user data submited)

I also attach some variables to request body

```
const perPage = 9
const page = req.query.p || 1
req.body.pagination = { perPage: perPage, page: page }
```

**Route middle-wares**

Now I have one last thing that I added `magicMiddleware` which is a sequence of middle-wares I construct at run-time (using this [connect-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-sequence) not an issue I guess, because it is used later and the problem is in the beginning of `magicMiddleware`)

```
function magicMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    const section = req.params[0]
    const method = req.method
    const { body } = req // Here body only contains { pagination: { perPage: 9, page: 1 } } !!!!!!
```

Fired as soon as this request is called

```
router.post(/^\/(donations|skills|blogs)/,
  magicMiddleware,
  async (req, res, next) => {
```

I really could not spot where it is going wrong, as body contains only the variable I added `{ pagination: { perPage: 9, page: 1 } }` and no POST data.

**EDIT**

[Request headers](https://ibb.co/1mK9d6h)

[Request payload](https://ibb.co/C73RgnM)

Comment: if you want to see all app middle-wares: https://github.com/bacloud14/Classified-ads-48/blob/hacktoberfest_only_branch/sexpress.js

Comment: Are you sending any files with your form on client side? If not, remove the `multipart/form-data` since this needs to be handled by a different parser. `multer` for example => https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: yes, I'm sending files and it was working at some point, i'm ashamed as I couldn't spot an earlier version where it works (file upload, indeed handled with multer, plus all other named input fields)

Comment: and multer middleware is being fired later, not earlier

Comment: Can you show the full Client side request?

Comment: I don't suspect that, this is why I didn't include the code here. Also I've checked the request in developer console. Please check this On Github: /views/partials/add_donation.ejs and also https://ibb.co/C73RgnM
https://ibb.co/1mK9d6h

Answer (score 0):

Simply my error was logical. I was expecting key-values to be parsed but at the moment `magicMiddleware` fires (the only middle-ware passed to Express), at the beginning Multer didn't executed already (executed only at the end). So at that moment `body` is not properly parsed by application level middle-ware

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
```

I had to detect the encoding type first, parse req object with an appropriate parser. In this case I chose `formidable`

```
async function magicMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    const contentType = req.get('content-type')
    const form = formidable({})
    if (contentType.indexOf('multipart/form-data') > -1) {
        await form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(String(err));
                return;
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify({ fields, files }, null, 2));
        })
    }
```